# Firefox Not Updating Because snapd not present

Tags: package-management, upgrade, firefox, dependencies, snap

**System Information:**

- Ubuntu 22.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to 22.04 a few days ago. A few months back I had uninstalled all snap related packages, including `snapd` because I had read on some online sources that snap packages may lead to a system slowdown. Moreover, they went against the spirit of open source. So enthusiastically I removed them. Thereafter, I had to reinstall the required packages, including Firefox, using `apt`. No issue in that.

After the upgrade, whenever I run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

I get the following output:

```bsh
The following packages have been kept back:
  firefox libomp-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I searched a bit online, and found that installing the said packages can resolve this issue.This method resolved the problem with libomp-dev, but **not firefox**. When I ran:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

I got:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 firefox : PreDepends: snapd but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I thought that if it is showing that my packages are broken, then

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

might help but to no avail.

So does this mean that I can no longer update my Firefox without reinstalling Snap or `snapd`?

Comment: You are not forced to reinstall `snapd` but you need to add a PPA to update `firefox`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)

Comment: "*I had read on some online sources that snap packages may lead to a system slowdown*" -- your online sources were misleading you. If you can reproduce snap runtime behavior that slows your whole system, the snap developers would love to see a bug report from you so they can reproduce it. Because right now their daily testing doesn't show any system slowdown at all.

Comment: It appears that you may still have the snap version of firefox installed, since it depends on snapd.  See answers to this question for guidance as to how to install the non-snap version. https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/243321

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firefox is no longer part of Canonical's `apt` repositories, as the goal is to have people using the Snap version to ensure security updates are rolled out in a timely manner. That said, if you would like to continue using a version of Firefox installed via a `.deb` package, you can get it directly from Mozilla.

Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Remove the currently-installed version of Firefox
2. Add Mozilla's PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
   ```
3. Update `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Install Firefox:

   ```
   sudo apt install firefox
   ```

So long as you do not have Snap installed, this will do what you're looking for without any additional steps

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04), you'll need to configure apt preferences and unattended upgrades to prevent reinstallation of the snap package.

Comment: @mook765 is that still required if Snap is not installed on the system?

Comment: Yes, it is required, you need to tell apt from which repository you want to install or upgrade firefox.

Comment: Yeah, it was required. Otherwise, the system was not linking my firefox application to the ppa repository I added. It would be helpful for future references if you could add @mook765 's part to your answer.